# UIPasteboard Pasteboard App iOS iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uipasteboard

I am looking forward developing a pasteboard app for the iPhone.

The question is: how can I realize when something has been copied? I know I can access the `UIPasteboard` generalPasteboard properties.

But when do I need to update the (example) `UITableView` that show the contents? Is there a notification sent to the `NSNotificationCenter` that I could observe? Anything else? Reload the data when `viewDidAppear`?

Comment: Huh, what? What exactly are you trying to achieve? This question is not quite clear.

Comment: I want to create an app that shows a list (in a table view for example) of all strings copied. There many apps like this. It stores what you copied so you can access the strings later. My question is when do I need to update the table contents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can register to the `UIPasteboardChangedNotification` notification ([documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPasteboard_Class/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008243-CH1-SW10)). This will be called each time the contents of the pasteboard changes.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was looking for. Sorry if I don't explain myself properly, I'm not english. I try my best! :) Thank you very much.